# HTML 5 or Objective-C & NativeSDK

Tags: html

I was wondering that if I want to make apps for both iOS as well as Android is it worth it to get into learning the whole HTML-CSS-JavaScript route or should I learn their native SDKs?

Exactly how much will HTML5 be the future I guess Im wondering. Is it going to really replace the native mobile app?

I know noone has a crystal ball but Im just seeking input from more experienced/or more senior developers.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The reality is that HTML5 will never be a realistic replacement for native applications built in iOS and Android, as it is not powerful or robust enough to do so. Additionally, using HTML5 will only work for you if you intend to create very simple apps. Even then, you will run into problems.

Consider for example the Table view in iOS. It can be highly optimized for speed and interaction in a way that will always surpass a third-party, remote solution such as HTML5. Note that the table view is one of the simplest things you will do when creating an iOS app.

Additionally, knowing Java (Android) and Objective-C (iOS) will be beneficial to you in the long run in terms of your development career.

There is one real exception: if your app is going to be the native representation of a web app (ie. Facebook) then it does in fact make sense to go with a largely web approach (HTML5/Javascript/CSS). In fact, that is exactly what Facebook did. However, even Facebook experienced a very buggy and crash-prone existence on mobile devices for the better part of a year.

In conclusion, I know of no application developer who seriously considers HTML5 as a contender for the building of mobile applications (other than for heavily web-based apps with web-like functionality). The dream, of course, is that HTML5 will be a "silver bullet" or a "golden hammer" for developers, ushering in a brave new age in which we are able to focus on learning one set of technologies for all sorts of devices. Unfortunately, it is merely a dream. At least for now.